# Passing Bash argument into Bash Variable encapsulating AWK Command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, solaris

I need to be able to run the script and pass in arguments (day and month) like

```
$root# ./myscript -v 31 12
```

but I can't seem to find any appropriate way to pass a command line argument into the awk command within the bash variable X without the script choking. I've tried double quotes to allow variable interpolation, escaping the other dollar signs with backslashes as outlined elsewhere on Stack Overflow, but to no avail.

```
#!/bin/bash
X=$(./some_script | awk -v VARIABLE="$1" '$1 == "VARIABLE" | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}')
Y=$(./other_script | awk -v VARIABLE="$2" '$1 == "VARIABLE" | awk '{print $1,$2,$3}')
echo '-------------RESULTS--------------'
echo
paste <(echo "$X") <(echo "$Y")
```

This is choking the script and returning an error

```
awk: syntax error near line 1 
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

***SOLVED***
Seems that the standard Solaris 'AWK' won't accept the -v flag, and that specific error telegraphed it somewhat. Switched it with nawk and it runs fine as detailed below. @David_W goes into some detail regarding nawk/awk parameter passing. Many thanks to @Ed_Morton for spotting the error and @anubhava and @hek2mgl for the Proof-of-concepts.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo
X=$(./some_script | nawk -v VARIABLE="$1" '$1 == "VARIABLE" {print $1,$2,$3}')
X=$(./other_script | nawk -v VARIABLE="$1" '$1 == "VARIABLE" {print $1,$2,$3}')
echo '-------------RESULTS--------------'
echo
paste <(echo "$X") <(echo "$Y")
```

Comment: Amended for clarity with thanks to contributors.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of passing environment variables into `awk` depending upon the version of `awk`:

Newer versions of `awk` (sometimes called `nawk` on Solaris systems):

```
$ awk -v var1="$var1" -v var2="$var2" prog.awk
```

Older versions of awk make you set the variables on the end:

```
$ awk prog.awk var1="$var1" var2="$var2"
```

I'm not 100% sure if that last one is exactly the way it's done. I haven't used the older version of `awk` in over 20 years. Even Solaris allows you to use the newer version of `awk` by either calling `nawk` instead, or by using the one in `/usr/xpg4/bin` (which I recommend to put in your `$PATH` before `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. This way, shell scripts from other operating systems like Mac OS X and Linux are more likely to work in a compatible way.)

From the Solaris XPG4 (Section 5) manpage:

> If the behavior required by POSIX.2, POSIX.2a, XPG4, SUS, or SUSv2 conflicts with historical Solaris utility behavior, the original Solaris version of the utility is unchanged; a new version that is standard-conforming has been provided in `/usr/xpg4/bin`. For applications wishing to take advantage of POSIX.2, POSIX.2a, XPG4, SUS, or SUSv2 features, the `PATH` (`sh` or `ksh`) or `path` (`csh`) environment variables should be set with `/usr/xpg4/bin` preceding any other directories in which utilities specified by those specifications are found, such as `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/ucb`, and `/usr/ccs/bin`.

Comment: FYI `nawk` (for `New AWK`) is an excellent example of why you should never use the word `New` in the name of any software as it's now old and lacking features of more modern awks. nawk is MUCH better than old, broken awk but /usr/xpg4/bin/awk is better than nawk, and gawk is better by a mile than any other available awk.

Comment: The original `awk` was written in 1977 by AT&T. BSD pretty much kept the same `awk` in the way it worked. (BSD is the Unix version Solaris was based off of). In 1980s, AT&T rewrote `awk` and called the new version `nawk`. When the _Unified Unix_ standard was created, `nawk` became the standard `awk`. SunOS and later Solaris kept the original BSD version of `awk` in their standard program directory for compatibility. I don't know if there's a difference between `nawk` and `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` and the way the operate. Don't get me started on `gawk` and other GNU versions of these utilities.

Comment: nawk supports a large subset of POSIX functionality, /usr/xpg4/bin/awk supports [almost] all POSIX functionality, gawk supports all POSIX functionality plus some very significantly useful extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk -v name=val` to pass an argument to `awk` from shell:

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
X=$(./some_script | awk -v val="HARDCODED" '$1 == val {print $1,$2,$3}')
Y=$(./some_other_script | awk -v val="HARDCODED" '$1 == val {print $1,$2,$3}')
echo '-------------RESULTS--------------'
echo
paste <(echo "$X") <(echo "$Y")
```

Comment: There's nothing faulty with the awk commands as they stand nor is the question addressed in your answer.

Comment: Ok let's talk about question. You wrote: **I can't seem to find any appropriate way to pass a command line argument into the awk command** Where exactly in your script you're passing an argument to `awk`? I can only guess that you're trying to pass something in place of `HARDCODED` but you do need to clarify it.

Comment: Fair enough - I thought 'HARDCODED' would be reasonably easy to figure out! Unfortunately, as I replied to hek2mgl, while that command would work with AWK on it's own, or AWK within a shell script, it seems to choke in the configuration above where AWk is called within a variable declaration within a shell script like the above. I don't think it's my configuration (Vanilla Solaris5) - have you tried out your suggestion in practice?

Comment: @LazyJim Please take it easy. You're not the boss here. You're just asking for help.

Comment: The OP finally posted the error message he's getting in a comment under @hex2mgls's answer and it tells us hes using old, broken awk. Once he switches to a modern awk he'll be fine.

Comment: Ah that's right, I just read. That old solaris awk is definitely not going to handle this `-v` option